# Insert comments in google sheet using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using setNote() function in Google script to add comments to a google sheet. However, I see that the comment is editable by anyone who has edit access to the sheet. The comment is a translated text which is output from the script and therefore should not be modified by the user. Is there a way I can add comments to the sheet in a similar manner as one can do manually, meaning it displays who added the comment and only that person can edit the comment (others can only reply to that comment, not edit original comment). Note that from setNote(), it does not display who added the comment.

Comment: thanks, taking cues form the link you shared , I tried writing a function using drive api, but that doesn't seem to work perfectly. Meaning, I can see the comment when I click on open comment history but it does not appear on the cell where I attached the comment. How do I share my sample code here?

Comment: I thought it was clear from the answer, the video in the answer, even the comments. You can't "anchor".

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I looked at Google help page which said you can, so got confused.